# Creating complex object from key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker

I have a file that has key/value pairs. This file is loaded inside the `process.env` via Docker. But for the development purposes I am loading it manually, so at the end they are identical;

The configuration:

```
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.level']='info';
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.type.file']='File';
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.filename']='logs/testOne.log';
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.rotate']='false';

process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.type.file']='File';
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.filename']='logs/testTwo.log';
process.env['ccc.logger.winston.transports.rotate']='true';
```

My expectation is to have this object:

```
{
  "ccc": {
    "logger": {
      "winston": {
        "level": "info",
        "transports": [
          {
            "type": "File",
            "filename": "logs/testONE.log",
            "rotate": true
          },
          {
            "type": "File",
            "filename": "logs/testTWO.log",
            "rotate": false
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have come up with solution that works ok, but i am having problems if I have an array of objects, just like in the above example:

**Code that loops all the keys/values and and calls function to create object:**

```
let ENV_FROM_DOCKER = process.env;

for (let property in ENV_FROM_DOCKER) {
  let checkForShallowProperties = property.split(".")[1];

  if (typeof checkForShallowProperties === 'undefined') {
    continue;
  }

  let resultObject = this.expand(property, ENV_FROM_DOCKER[property]););

  emptyConfig = merge(emptyConfig, resultObject);
  let stop;
}
```

**Object creation function:**

```
expand(str, value) {
  let items = str.split(".") // split on dot notation
  let output = {} // prepare an empty object, to fill later
  let ref = output // keep a reference of the new object

  //  loop through all nodes, except the last one
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i++) {
    ref[items[i]] = {}; // create a new element inside the reference
    ref = ref[items[i]]; // shift the reference to the newly created object
  }

  ref[items[items.length - 1]] = value; // apply the final value
  return output // return the full object
}
```

This setup works fine, But if I have an object that has array of objects (like in an example above), than it does not work properly. This is the output now:

```
{
  "ccc": {
    "logger": {
      "winston": {
        "level": "info",
        "transports": {
          "type": {
            "file": "File"
          },
          "filename": "logs/testTwo.log",
          "rotate": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get this code working for hours now, but just spinning in the circles. The `ccc` object is one example. There are going to be other objects in the key/value list that might have also arrays as well.

Comment: If there ANY way apart from `transports.type.file` appearing multiple times to deduce that transports has to be an array? Does the script have to work for various different key/value pairs with different structures? Or only for this specific one? If it's only for this specific one, i'd just write out the entire object key structure and only fill in the values. If it has to work for different structured files, we do need a 100% reliable way to say what should and should not be an array.

Comment: If you have control over the docker, I would advice to actually change the structure of the file sent so there's no ambiguity. It's close to JSON, but not quite.

Comment: Yes. I have control over the docker file. I can create the key/value pairs. there could be other objects as well, that have this structure. the application at the receiving end expects this object.

Comment: Then can't you just format the docker file as actual valid JSON so you don't have to create this object at all and can just parse the file?

Comment: That was my idea to begin with, create a single key that holds entire JSON. And simply parse it. But I was told not to do that, for reasons that it not safe. That JSON might not get parsed properly... the size of it. I dont agree with the explanation, but I was told anyways not to do it.

Comment: Euh, a JSON either is valid or not. Valid JSONs always parse. Invalid JSONs never parse. And certainly doing this whole thing this way will take more memory that starting with a JSON file to begin with. So the person who told you that is BS'ing. Can you explain how the process.env object is able to hold duplicate keys? Or are the two examples you gave two different files parsed seperately?

Comment: Working example is being created with the env that does not have docker. It is simple YML file, that is being parsed and JSON created. There is no danger for duplicate keys, as all object have different starting names.

Comment: HINT: I suggest you to use bash arrays ( http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) so you don't want to load each variable one by one (just process that array key by key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assign each transport an index

While creating your environment variables you can assign each `transports.whatnot` to an index in an array `transports[0].whatnot` and `transports[1].whatnot`. To make this work we will have to parse it like so:

```js
const ENV = {
  'ccc.logger.winston.level': 'info',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[0].type': 'File',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[0].filename': 'logs/testOne.log',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[0].rotate': 'false',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[1].type': 'File',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[1].filename': 'logs/testTwo.log',
  'ccc.logger.winston.transports[1].rotate': 'true'
}

for (let property in ENV) {
  let checkForShallowProperties = property.split('.')[1]; 

  if (typeof checkForShallowProperties === 'undefined') {
    continue;
  }

  let resultObject = expand(property, ENV[property])
  console.log(resultObject)
}

function expand(string, value) {
  const items = string.split('.').map(name => {
    const match = name.match(/\[\d+?\]/)
    return {
      name: match ? name.slice(0, match.index) : name,
      usesBrackets: !!match,
      key: match && match[0].slice(1, -1)
    }
  })
  
  const output = {}
  let ref = output
  let parent
  
  for (const item of items) {
    ref[item.name] = {}
    parent = ref
    ref = ref[item.name]
    if (item.usesBrackets) {
      ref[item.key] = {}
      ref = ref[item.key]
    }
  }
  parent[items[items.length - 1].name] = value
  return output
}
```

### The output here is PRE-MERGE

As you can see, the way it works is by treating the object as its own array and placing content at the indices, or even other accessors.

However, **it would most likely be in your best interest to move all of this over to a `.json` file** or some *content management system*, as this is a very volatile way of doing things. If your needs change you may need to rewrite this, *with JSON you just load the JSON*.

Comment: I am currently trying it out :)

Comment: I am currently getting: stack trace: ReferenceError: items is not defined. Trying to resolve it

Comment: Oh, try `const items = ` I didn't declare it

Comment: Just updated code, fixed duplicating last key issue with `parent = ref`

Comment: It runs, but it does two different things. First one: transports should be an array of objects. Second one: type is created as an object as well.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. The first one: Arrays are objects with numbered indices so it should work just as well. The second one: you have to change your ENV Variable from `.type.file='File'` to `.type='File'` to get that to happen

Comment: Are you saying that code that uses this numbered indices is agnostic, and that it should work regardless?. Previously there was transports: [{}, {}]. And now is transports: {0:{}, 1:{}}. I need to go after this code to see is anything broken or not.

Comment: Yeah, they are essentially the same for accessing purposes, the only difference is that you dont get all those extra functions and whatnot, however if you need to convert it to an array after the fact you can give it a `.length` and use `Array.from`. To iterate over, use `for ... in` I believe

Comment: I am trying to understand this code, and make it create an array inside the transport :)

Answer (score 2):

If you change your logic a little, and provide the value as *split-able*, maybe you could do something like this, where it is easier to detect what is *keys* and *values*, and if a value is *split-able*, you know to *push* it as an array.

There is yet one more decision to make, and that is how it should understand when values should add to a given object array, e.g. `transports` array object, or create a new.

Maybe if the key exists in that array object, like in below snippet?

Stack snippet

```js
var res = {};
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.level','info');
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','type=File1');
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','filename=logs/testOne.log');
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','rotate=false');

expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','type=File2');
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','filename=logs/testTwo.log');
expand(res,'ccc.logger.winston.transports','rotate=true');

console.log( res )

function expand(ref, str, value) {
    let items = str.split(".") // split on dot notation

    //  loop through all key nodes
    for(let i = 0; i < items.length - 1; i ++)
    {
        if (!ref[items[i]])
          ref[items[i]] = {}; // create if not exist
          
        ref = ref[items[i]]; // shift the object reference
    }
    
    let values = value.split("=") // split on equal sign

    if (values.length > 1)
    {
        // apply array
        var item = ref[items[items.length - 1]];
        
        if (item) {
            //  add to array
            if(!item[item.length - 1][values[0]]) {
                item[item.length - 1][values[0]] = values[1]; // add to existing array
            } else {
                item.push( {[values[0]]: values[1]} ); // create new array item
            }
        } else {
            // create array        
            ref[items[items.length - 1]] = [ {[values[0]]: values[1]} ];
        }
        
    } else {
        // apply value
        ref[items[items.length - 1]] = value;
    }

    //return ref; // return the full object
}
```

---

A few notes:

- When assigning an object key using an array variable like this, `{[values[0]]: values[1]}`, the *key* need to be enclosed in brackets `[]`.

  For browsers not support ES6, use a normal variable, e.g.

  ```
  var key = values[0];
  {key: values[1]}
  ```
- `Object.assign` is usually used to merge object, though if a key exists, the value gets overwritten.

  To overcome that, I passed an object reference to the *expand* function.

Comment: ref[items[items.length - 1]].push( {values[0]: values[1]} ); ... yields SyntaxError: Unexpected token [...

Comment: Code is running now. I do get an array, but it is missing Filename and type. this is the output: {
  "logger": {
    "winston": {
      "level": "info",
      "transports": [
        {
          "rotate": "false"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I need to set up a runnable test code. Will notify you when done.

Comment: I see the problem. There are same names for the keys, and they are overwritten. ccc.logger.winston.transports is always overwritten with the last value

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I have updated my answer with a running code, and added a few notes.

Comment: @VedranMaricevic. I rewrote my answer and added sample that create the object you asked for.